# Search a text in all custom button Javascript

Tags: custom-button, metadata

I would like to know if a particular field being referred in any of our Javascripts written for the various custom buttons on-click event. Is it possible to search and identify?

Answer (score 0):

We can fetch the code using Eclipse , and then Ctrl + H to find the term would help.

Comment: Please explain the process to fetch the code with the Force.com IDE.

Comment: To install Force.com IDE, 
please refer: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/ide_install.htm 

And to create force.com project, 
please refer : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/ide_pro_create_project.htm